# Where in delete with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

I have two arrays like,

```
$sub_id=array(1,2);
$field_id=array(2,3);
```

I was try to delete some records from my table like

```
$this->db->where_in('sub_id',$sub_id);
$this->db->where_in('field_id',$field_id);
```

Now it will delete 4 records with (1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3).But i need to delete only (1,2) and (2,3),

I mean delete records from table with array haveing same key.
is possible with `$this->db->where_in()`

Comment: Use join with where_in

Comment: could you `echo $this->db->last_query();` after the `$this->db->delete(...);` so we can see what query is being executed when you run this? EDIT... I don't think this is possible the way you are attempting to do it, maybe write a manual query `WHERE (sub_id = 1 AND field_id = 2) OR (sub_id = 2 AND field_id = 3)` I'm not sure how you would write that with CI active recordset methods

Comment: Even something like this is not working: `$this->db->delete('user_permissions', ['user_id IN' => '(' + implode(',', $userIds) + ')']);`